# What is the best way to invalid an expression for debugging?

Tags: php, conditional-statements

Consider:

```
if ($expression1) {
    // code block 1
} else {
    // code block 2
}
```

To debug code block 1, I can prefix `TRUE ||` to `$expression1` to get it to evaluate to `TRUE`:

```
if (TRUE || $expression1) {
    // code block 1
} else {
    // code block 2
}
```

But how would I get `$expression1` to evaluate to `FALSE` in order to debug code block 2? I usually resort to this:

```
if (1==0 && $expression1) {
    // code block 1
} else {
    // code block 2
}
```

Is there a less opaque way?

Comment: I would comment out parts instead.

Comment: Why the downvote? This may be small but it is a legitimate question and it has bugged me for years.

Comment: Well, I did not downvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be symmetrical to the second approach:

```
if (FALSE && $expression1) {
    // code block 1
} else {
    // code block 2
}
```

Comment: That it what I thought, but I would swear that on occasions it didn't work. :(

Answer (score 0):

To not complicate things, use either this:

```
// code block 1
```

or this

```
// code block 2
```

and when you are done, you use this:

```
if ($expression1) {
    // code block 1
} else {
    // code block 2
}
```

You accomplish this with the undo functionality.

Comment: Seems more complicated to me. You are changing multiple lines and relying on undo functionality. What if I want to keep the debugging in place for a day? The line is flagged with a comment, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I comment out the existing and replace it with true or false.

For true:

```
if (true){ // $expression1) {
    // code block 1
} else {
    // code block 2
}
```

For false:

```
if (false){ // $expression1) {
    // code block 1
} else {
    // code block 2
}
```

Comment: Perhaps this is the clearest way. I would thank you for it but don't have enough points and am no closer now that someone has voted down my question. :(